# El Gamal exponent finding algorithm

Tags: c, cryptography

I am trying to find the exponent of a number Z whose modulo X will give Y.
This is my code:

```
int main()
{

    int a = 607;

    int gen = 28;
    long long b = 28;

    int c = 597;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10000000000)
    {
        b = b * gen;
        if ((b % a) == c)
        {
            printf("%ld\n", b);
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code implements the El Gamal algorithm of calculating the exponent. 
The program should return 153, but instead, it goes over and iterates until the end. Can anyone shed some light on this for me, please?

Comment: The value of a 32-bit integer will **always** be less than 10000000000 (ten billion)

Comment: Also, `printf` requires `%lld` to print a `long long`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread.

Comment: Note: `b * gen` can readily overflow.  I think `b = (b * gen)%a;` would be useful

Comment: Confusing that code uses `a,b,c,i` when the goal is expressed in `X, Y, Z`.

Comment: If you are starting to Cryptography with C, you should start using gnu gmp

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate your description and your code share no variable names in common. You made small mistakes and one big one: you did not take the intermediate result mod a. Here is my code with the few modifications:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a = 607;

    int gen = 28;
    int b = 1;

    int c = 597;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < a)
    {
        b = (b * gen) % a;
        // invariant: b == (gen**i) % a
        if (b == c)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

You will need to be more careful when doing arithmetic; it is surprisingly brittle to the new programmer. Overflow lurks around every corner, and for floating types underflow is also a predator. Never trust a+b, a-b, a/b, or a*b to always produce what mathematics says it should.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1) The comparison with 10000000000 will always be true because the maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer is a bit over 4 billion, so it's always going to be less than 10 billion. Using `long long i` will make it a 64-bit integer on many platforms.

2) Printing the result requires `%lld` so `printf()` knows to find a `long long` value

3) The 64-bit value `long long b` will overflow after 14 trips around the loop, so the other 10 billion loops are working with wrapped-around integers.  Unless the El Gamal algorithm is designed around modulo arithmetic - I don't know one way or another - I don't see how this is ever going to work.

In the code below, I've added a check for when `b` went negative, which would indicate overflow; I don't know if this is the best way to do this in practice.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 607;

    int gen = 28;
    long long b = 28;

    int c = 597;
    long long i = 1;      // formerly int
    while (b > 0  &&  i < 10000000000)
    {
        b *= gen;
        if ((b % a) == c)
        {
            printf("%lld\n", b);       // Formerly %ld
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("Fell off bottom: i=%lld\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

And then running it on my system:

> Fell off bottom: i = 14

Comment: add a statement before if - `b = b % a` and use `b == c`